# Laravel: "override" request object?

Tags: php, laravel-5, controller

I have a function where I save a group. I want to "access" it from the page (when the user makes a new group with a form) and from a controller, too (when a process makes a new group, for example when I create a new tenant)

My code is so far:

```
.
.
.

$this->saveGroup($tenantId, 'Default group');

.
.
.

public function saveGroup(Request $request, $tenantId = 0, $nameFromFunction = ''){
    if(!empty($request)){
        $name = $request -> name;
    } elseif($nameFromFunction != ''){
        $name = $nameFromFunction;
    } else {
        $name = '';
    }

    if($tenantId > 0 && $name != ''){
        $group = new ConversationGroup;
        $group -> group_name = $name;
        $group -> tenant_id = $tenantId;

        $group->save();
    }

    if($nameFromFunction != ''){
        return $group -> id; //if a function calls it
    } else {
        return redirect("/{$tenantId}/groups"); //if the new group was made from the page
    }
}
```

If I test it with the page's group creation form it works fine, but when I run it from the controller I got the following error:

> GroupController::saveGroup() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, integer given

What I must change if I want to earn this logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use global [request()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-request) helper and completely avoid passing `Request` object to your function, like:

```
public function saveGroup($tenantId = 0, $nameFromFunction = ''){
    //get input named 'name' or default to $nameFromFunction
    $name = request('name', $nameFromFunction);
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening, is because in your function definition, first parameter is not `$tenantId`, but the object of class request.

So you have to pass an object of request class as a first parameter to get this working.

Comment: And how can I do it from controller. If I make a `$request` object it still won't work becouse it's not the object what was made with `Illuminate/Http/Request` class

Answer (score 0):

You should try this way,

```
public function otherFunction()
{
    $this->saveGroup(new Request(['name' => 'Default Group']), $tenantID);
                       OR
    $this->saveGroup(new Request(), $tenantID, "Default Group");
}    

public function saveGroup(Request $request, $id = 0, $nameFromFunction = '')
{
    echo 'here-your-code';        
}
```